# How to write a reusable JavaScript plugin code with ease of applying only a class?

Tags: javascript, html, plugins

I was just wondering that how can I use JavaScript to create a reusable component that can be used several times in my project. For example, If I want to create a widget that can be used more than one times on a single HTML page then what to do? Below is the example to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

HTML:

```
<div id="ele1" class="myclass">
</div>
```

Here, I have taken an html container element, in which I want to append all the requirements to create my custom plugin.

JS:

```
(function() {
   var ww = function(el) { // core constructor
     // ensure to use the `new` operator
     if (!(this instanceof ww))
      return new ww(el);
     // store an argument for this example
     this.el = el;
   };

   // create `fn` alias to `prototype` property
   ww.fn = ww.prototype = {
    init: function () {}
   };

   // expose the library
   window.ww = ww;
})();
```

To create and assign a prototype named **fn** to the particular element above code is required.

Then iterate the all element to call the plugin for the specific class **myclass** like below:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByClassName("weather").length; i++){
    ww(document.getElementsByClassName("weather")[i]).WeatherWidget();
  }
}, false);
```

Now I can assign any method to that element using **ww.fn** in above example, like this:

```
ww.fn.MyWidget = function () {
  var me = this.el;
  return new ww.fn.widgetConstruct(me);
};
```

Here, **widgetConstruct()** is the method that includes all the business logic of the component.

```
ww.fn.widgetConstruct = function(me){

   function initialize(){
      ....
      The component logic will go here
      ....
   }
   initialize();
}
```

I you want to see the full example then this is a plnkr [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/AMWsMQ3pUIC6Jiw8XoJa?p=preview) for a **Weather Widget**

Answer (score 0):

The modern way is to use a framework like React.js, Angular or Vue.js.

React.js is made for doing exactly this.